# How to know the position of notification in android

Tags: android, list, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to display list of elements in notification bar. Now I have a set of notifications but every notification I am clicking takes me to same activity i.e. I was not able to store the position of notification.

Here is my code

```
    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(
                            "Coupon Received From "
                                    + list.get(i).merchantName)
                    .setContentText(
                            "Coupon Value : "
                                    + list.get(i).couponValue)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker("Coupon alert message from Kluebook")
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250 });

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,
                    CouponDetailActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("couponid",
                    list.get(i).couponid);
            resultIntent.putExtra("position", list.get(i).i);
            resultIntent.putExtra("branchid",
                    list.get(i).issuedBranchid);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, 0, resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(i + 1, mBuilder.build());

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("+++++++++++ IT IS EMPTY +++++++++++++++ list");
      }
   }
```

If I get 5 notifications in notification bar, every notification takes me to first notification activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same context to create all the notifications' PendingIntent, I think all these notifications are taking you to the same activity (in your case CouponDetailActivity). So I would try creating different notifications with different Activity's context and pending intent and that should take you to your desired activity!

Comment: I got my solution by keeping `i` instead of `0` in pendingintent